# Change default key from JS object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, lodash

How can I change the default keys generated by the transform() method from Lodash for this object. They must start from 1, instead of 0.

```
function getHashValues(section, matchExp) {
    var picked = _.transform(section, function(result, value, key) {
        var matches = key.match(new RegExp(matchExp));
        if (matches) {
            result[matches[2]] = result[matches[2]] || {};
            result[matches[2]][matches[1]] = value;
        }
    }, {});

    // Log
    console.log(typeof picked); // object
    console.log(picked); // Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object}

    return picked;
}
```

Comment: Without trying, I'd say use `result[matches[2] + 1]`.

Comment: Can you show us the usage of `getHashValues`?

Comment: As said by @user3557327... You probably want _.reduce instead of _.transform (you don't transform section, do you?) and _.transform doesn't generate keys, you generate them with the [] notation... Side note: put `new RegEx` in a var at the start of getHashValues, to save some CPU cycles.